# Database Join - Right Join?

Tags: database, join

I have two tables shown below

Table 1 :
[image: Table 1]

Table 2 :

[image: Table 2]

I am looking for a join that would result in a table like this

Result : 
[image: Result]

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show what parts you can do & explain how you are stuck. [mcve] Now you are just asking us to do your homework for you. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: We can't really give you a query without knowing why the first record only selectively joins to one of the two phone number records.  Unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: In addition to Tim's question - what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @ZainFarooq  Please do not inline links inappropriately. See my comment above re using text whenever possible. Either replace a link to a table by code block formatted tabular text (which should simultaneously be code to create & initialize a table if the question should give a [mcve]) or, much better, comment to tell the poster to do it. PS This is unclear so should not be answered; it should be downvoted & close voted. When it's clear it will be a faq; it should be downvoted & close voted.

Comment: provide the code that you have already tried. It is not clear how to answer this question

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT t2.Employee_ID,t1.Name,t1.Id,t2.Area_Code,t2.Phone_Number FROM dbo.Table_2 t2 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table_1 t1  ON t1.Employee_ID=t2.Employee_ID
```

Comment: That query does not give the requested result. See the comments on the question. PS This is unclear so should not be answered; it should be downvoted & close voted. When it's clear it will be a faq; it should be downvoted & close voted. If it weren't a faq or unclear it should be downvoted & closed for not having a [mcve]--if it had one, you could have run your query & seen it was wrong.